# How to set value of Session to LoginName without Membership in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, login-control

I have `MasterRoot.Master` and `LoginPage.aspx`

How can I set value of `Session` to `HeadLoginName` after user success Login.

**Login.aspx.cs**

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    UserClass user=new UserClass();
    user.LoginProcess(txtUserName.Text,txtPass.Text);

    if(user.loginsuccess) {

        Session["UserName"]=user.username.ToString();
    }
}
```

**MasterRoot.Master.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    // Like this HeadLoginName.Text=Session["UserName"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: How do you authenticate your users?

Comment: I have Persons table in SQL.I want to use this table for users login.Because there are some special fields in this table.I must use those fields in my project.

Comment: So is your question about the problem of saving the `UserName` value to the session or about authentication based on custom table?

Comment: No.I am using Persons table for login.I want HeadLoginName will take Session value.Is it possible ?

Comment: If you already have a value saved in session object just access it as you showed in your code example: `Session["UserName"].ToString();`

Comment: I know.But I want when User success login HeadLoginName : Welcome UserName

Answer (score 0):

The Load() event in the master page is executed before you assigns the Session["UserName"] and therefor it is empty after the user clicked on the Login. You either need to use Response.Redirect to redirect to some page and "refresh" a page or assign the value of the Label on master page directly from content page

```
if(user.loginsuccess) {
    Session["UserName"]=user.username.ToString();

   // Gets a reference to a Label control that not in a ContentPlaceHolder
   Label mpLabel = (Label) Master.FindControl("HeadLoginName");
   if(mpLabel != null)
      Label1.Text = user.username; 
}
```

Read more about how [to access Master page from Content page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xxwa0ff0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and about [Events in ASP.NET Master and Content Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dct97kc3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

if you just wanted to assign the session value with out any exception you can do like this in master page

```
HeadLoginName.Text=(Session["username"]==null)?"some value you like":Session["username"];
```

and when the user logged in successfully you can give like this in child page

```
 Session["username"]=usernametxt.Text;
```

Then the value will be assigned in your master page on the page postback;